# rData.substr(x, y) to QString to append to text field

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Basically, I'm receivng data and storing it in a std::string variable called "receivedData".

I want specific parts of this variable so here's what I do:

```
                size_t start = 1;
                size_t end = receivedData.find("ABC");
```

I want to append this specific part of my received data to a text edit field, so I try:

```
 QString specificPart = receivedData.substr(start, end - start);
 ui->textEdit->append(specificPart);
```

Which gives me this error: " error: conversion from 'std::basic_string' to non-scalar type 'QString' requested "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is telling you rather cleanly that it doesn't know how to convert an `std::basic_string` into a `QString`. You need to do the conversion yourself.

Assuming that the `std::string` is encoded in Utf-8, you can use `QString::fromStdString`:

```
size_t start = 1;
size_t end = receivedData.find("ABC");
QString specificPart = QString::fromStdString(receivedData)
                       .mid(start, end - start);
ui->textEdit->append(specificPart);
```